# PMML: I can get the probability of a random forest class prediction, but why can i not get the confidence score?

Tags: random-forest, pmml

Below is a short snippet (excerpt) of my random forest in PMML format

```
    <Segmentation multipleModelMethod="majorityVote">
      <Segment id="0">
        <True/>
        <TreeModel functionName="classification" algorithmName="mtree" missingValueStrategy="lastPrediction" modelName="train">
          <Node score="0" recordCount="450655">
            <True/>
            <ScoreDistribution value="0" recordCount="450291" confidence="0.9991" probability="0.99919"/>
            <ScoreDistribution value="1" recordCount="364" confidence="7.3E-4" probability="8.1E-4"/>
            <Node score="0" recordCount="44603">
              <SimplePredicate operator="greaterThan" field="IDVAR_EUR" value="1112"/>
              <ScoreDistribution value="0" recordCount="44239" confidence="0.99096" probability="0.99184"/>
              <ScoreDistribution value="1" recordCount="364" confidence="0.00737" probability="0.00816"/>
```

When I have the following global Output specification I can get the predicted value and the probability of each class label:

```
    <p:Output xmlns:p="http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_3">
      <p:OutputField name="probability1" optype="continuous" datatype="double" feature="probability" value="1"/>
      <p:OutputField name="probability0" optype="continuous" datatype="double" feature="probability" value="0"/>
```

But when I add additional lines for confidence score output, then I get now result at all!

```
    <p:Output xmlns:p="http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_3">
      <p:OutputField name="probability1" optype="continuous" datatype="double" feature="probability" value="1"/>
      <p:OutputField name="probability0" optype="continuous" datatype="double" feature="probability" value="0"/>
      <p:OutputField name="confidence1" optype="continuous" datatype="double" feature="confidence" value="1"/>
      <p:OutputField name="confidence0" optype="continuous" datatype="double" feature="confidence" value="0"/>
    </p:Output>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps your PMML engine doesn't support the `confidence` result feature? If it sees an `OutputField@feature="confidence"` instruction, it crashes?

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  In fact I am using jpmml evaluator to make prediction with the PMML file.  Using the Output specification from above but with a decision tree model I can get all five output:  predicted value, probability of predicting class 0, probability of predicting class 1, confidence of predicting class 0, and confidence of predicting class 1.